# Python code for BITalino accelerometry measurements

Tags: python, accelerometer, nano

I have been trying to find information about what the Python script for extracting and ploting the accelerometry data measured by a BITalino device is, but I am not able to find any useful information. Does anyone have such script?

Thank you very much!

I tried searching for this code in GitHub and in BITalino manuals, but I cannot find anything. I plotted the electrocardiogram data easily, but not the accelerometry.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this site is not a code-writing or tutoring service, it is best used when you have a specific problem with written code. Your question, reads like "Can someone code this for me" or "Show me a tutorial or information on how to code this" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour], read [what are you asking].